# TYPESCRIPT dependent interface variables

Tags: typescript, interface

my interface looks something like this:

```
export interface Woman {
  active: boolean;
  type: PersonType;
  houseAddress?: Address;
  houseNumber?: number;
}
```

but, i want a default value for houseNumber if houseAddress isnt specified.. something like this:

```
export interface Woman {
  active: boolean;
  type: PersonType;
  houseAddress?: Address;
  houseNumber?: houseAddress ? number : 15; //if it is specified, take the number from input, else have default value 
}
```

is there something like that possible? thanks a lot for answers!

Comment: It kind of seems like you want a union, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJyJZm) shows.  But interfaces can't be unions, so maybe that won't work for you? If it does work I can write up an answer explaining it.  If not, please [edit] the question to show a code example where you have an unmet need.

Comment: An interface doesn't exist in runtime, so having a default value on an interface doesn't make a lot of sense. Unless you want something that enforces through its type that the number 15 is used, which could be done by having two interfaces.